# Designing small letters under words in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, layers

I want to design small letters under words in QGIS when I designed the labels (attach picture).

Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340539/designing-small-letters-under-words-in-qgis#comment556690_340539):

> … I found a this website https://lingojam.com/SmallTextGenerator, it
>   helps us copy the text kind of subscript and paste it directly into
>   QGIS